# Set deliver_later_queue_name for inherited ActionMailer object in Rails 5.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to set up separate mailer queues for transaction mail processing and bulk mail processing in my Rails 5.1.3 application.   According to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)
 (Configuration Options), I should be able to designate the queue by setting the `deliver_later_queue_name`.

I have the following classes:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
end

class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer  self.deliver_later_queue_name = 'mail'
  self.deliver_later_queue_name = 'mail'
  self.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 587,
    ...
}

class BulkMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.deliver_later_queue_name = 'bulkmail'
  self.smtp_settings = {
    address: "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    port: 587,
    ...
  }
```

This works fine for the smtp_settings, but the `deliver_later_queue_name` appears to be a class variable? and so when I set it in the `BulkMailer` or `UserMailer`, it changes it for all the ActionMailer's.

Does anyone know a way for me to set separate `deliver_later_queue_name`'s for my BulkMailer and UserMailer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`deliver_later_queue_name` is defined with `cattr_accessor` (see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/127b475dc251a06942fe0cd2de2e0545cf5ed69f/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb#L15)). From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-mattr_accessor) of `cattr_accessor` you can see that:

> If a subclass changes the value then that would also change the value for parent class. Similarly if parent class changes the value then that would change the value of subclasses too.

So there's isn't a easy way you can do this using `deliver_later_queue_name`.

One options would be to set the queue at enqueue time:

```
BulkMailer.offer(offer, user).deliver_later(queue: :bulkemail)
```

Another options would be if you want to run rails edge by this using `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_job` which is defined with `class_attribute` so you can override it in subclasses (documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-class_attribute)).

The implementation would be:

```
class RegularEmailsJob < ActionMailer::DeliveryJob
  queue_as :mail
end
class BulkEmailsJob < ActionMailer::DeliveryJob
  queue_as :bulkmail
end

class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.deliver_job = RegularEmailsJob
  # ...
end

class BulkMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.deliver_job = BulkEmailsJob
  # ...
end
```

Another similar options would be for you not to rely on `deliver_later` and have your own jobs that are delivering the emails with `deliver_now`:

```
class EmailsDeliveryJob
  def perform(mailer_class, mailer_method, *args)
    mailer_class.send(mailer_method, *args)
  end
end
class RegularEmailsJob < EmailsDeliveryJob
  queue_as :mail
end
class BulkEmailsJob < EmailsDeliveryJob
  queue_as :bulkmail
end

# and when you want to send an email you do
RegularEmailsJob(UserMailer, :welcome, @user)

# At this point you can get creative in making your syntax better (a helper)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very clear, informative answer!

Comment: I can't reproduce the same conditions in Rails 5.2.3